# how to unstage changes in workspace with git?

Tags: git

I am trying to get rid of a 'new file' in my workspace. When I run 'git status' I get something like:

```
..
    new file: filepath/filename
    untracked files:....
```

I would like to unstage this file. I tried to run :

```
git reset HEAD filepath/filename
```

and:

```
git checkout filepath/filename
```

But when I run git status nothing is changed or the new file still appears with the message 'new file..' (see above). How can I get rid of this file so I can push the rest of my code?

Comment: `git rm --cached filepath/filename`

Comment: If you want to remove the file from your working directory, leave out the `--cached`. Using `--cached` stops tracking the file but leaves it in the working directory. Also, for future reference, you can use `git reset -- filepath/filename` to un-include a staged change from your next commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any more output around the `git status`?

When I run the scenario, `git status` suggests using `git reset HEAD path/to/file`, which works:

```
my-mac:my_repo acanby$ echo "test file" > test.txt
my-mac:my_repo acanby$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
my-mac:my_repo acanby$ git add test.txt 
my-mac:my_repo acanby$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   test.txt

my-mac:my_repo acanby$ git reset HEAD test.txt
my-mac:my_repo acanby$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```